# Multiple instances of socket using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, websocket, socket.io

In a part of my web app there are items with detailed notes that can be edited by several people at once. This was causing issues so I decided to implement socket.io so that changes would be pushed in real time. It is working great. The issue is that I am using the same socket for all notes. If two people are editing two different notes, I would expect them to use different sockets. I don't even know how to search this issue. I would imagine each socket is unique by note ID. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use a separate socket for editing a different note.  When you send an edit for a note, you can just send an id for the note with the edit so that when a server receives an edit, it knows exactly which note the edit belongs to.

If you want more specific help, you will have to show us your actual code.

> If two people are editing two different notes, I would expect them to use different sockets.

That is not required and is probably not desirable either.  You can send messages retaining to many different notes over the same socket.  A socket is merely a communications channel.  It doesn't have to be tied to a specific piece of data.  You just need to include with the message you are sending some sort of identifier so the recipient of the message knows which data this message pertains to.

Comment: That makes sense. I am sending the note ID to make sure only the correct note is updated with the text. The issue is that regardless of which note is actually updated in the database, all clients currently connected to that socket will get the output of the updated text. I can still make sure only the same note is updated, but why receive 200 responses/minute that don't relate to your note? What is best practice for this? Should I keep track of which client is on which note and somehow only push to those clients editing the same note? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @cbrawl - You can use the server-side concept of "rooms" to manage who gets sent which data.  If your server knows which clients are interested in which notes, it can add that client's socket to a room who's name is derived from the id of the note.  A connection can be in more than one room.  Then, when a note is modified, you can broadcast to all clients in that room with `io.to(roomId).emit(...)`.  You will have to maintain the rooms so a client is added or removed from a room for a specific note appropriately.  See `socket.join()` and `socket.leave()` on the server.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. I will investigate rooms.